# Alternative inference rule to modus ponens

Tags: logic

Modus ponens says:  from $P \rightarrow Q$, and $P$, deduce $Q$.

Consider the following rule:  from $P \rightarrow Q$, and $\neg P \rightarrow Q$, deduce $Q$.  I will call this inference rule, "rule 2."  Note that rule 2 is valid (assuming excluded middle).

Rule 2 is more general than modus ponens.  The conclusion of modus ponens is the same as the conclusion of rule 2, and the premises of rule 2 are weaker than the premises of modus ponens.  In other words, the premises of modus ponens imply the premises of rule 2, but not vice versa.  Specifically, $P \rightarrow Q$ implies $P \rightarrow Q$, and $P$ implies $\neg P \rightarrow Q$.  We could say that rule 2 starts with less than modus ponens, and does just as much.

Rule 2 has a couple of additional mildly interesting properties.  The two premises of rule 2 are essentially interchangeable, unlike modus ponens.  Also Rule 2 is reversible:  from $Q$, we can deduce $P \rightarrow Q$ and $\neg P \rightarrow Q$.

My question is this.  Are there any established logics that lack modus ponens, but have rule 2 in place of it?

Comment: No, rule 2 is not strictly more general.  You have assumed law of excluded middle here.

Comment: @user10354138 ok.  Assuming excluded middle it's more general.

Comment: Why more general? But yes, it is a "rule", because $(P \to Q) \to ((\lnot P \to Q) \to Q)$ is a tautology and from every tautology of "form" $\alpha \to \beta$ we can derive the corresponding rule: "from $\alpha$, derive $\beta$"

Comment: The "reverse" is simply a particular case of Conditional Introduction: from $Q$, derive $X \to Q$, with $X$ whatever.

Comment: Modus Ponens is only half a definition of implication, you need the deduction theorem to complete it.  For your rule, the reverse, $Q \vdash (P \to Q) \land (\lnot P \to Q)$ combined with rule 2 does not fully define implication.  Because in both rules $\to$ can be replaced by $\lor$ (alternatively, with $\land$) and still be "valid" rules.  So you still need another rule to define implication, even if the completeness of negation is taken for granted.  Also thanks for being responsive to feedback to your question, +1 from me.

Comment: Also, not saying another rule couldn't be constructed, just that the logic you are looking for would need it.

Comment: @DanielV for the implication introduction rule, I would suggest:  from $P \rightarrow Q \vdash Q$ deduce $\neg P \rightarrow Q$.  Note that a conditional proof with MP has the form, "(one premise of MP) $\vdash$ (conclusion of MP).  Therefore, (other premise of MP)."  A conditional proof using the implication introduction rule just mentioned has the analogous form, "(one premise of rule 2) $\vdash$ (conclusion of rule 2).  Therefore, (other premise of rule 2)."